# I want to generate String based on configuration array

Tags: javascript, java

I have an array of object.

```
[{id:"a5", parent: a3, value:"great grand child conmpnent"},
{id:"a1", parent: null, value:"parent conmpnent"},
{id:"a2", parent: a1, value:"child conmpnent"},
{id:"a3", parent: a2, value:"grand child conmpnent"},
{id:"a4", parent: a2, value:"grand child conmpnent"}]
```

I want to generate below String, based on this array.
can any body help..
*Formatting doesn't matter, it's a String only*

[image]

Comment: nice idea, what have you tried?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please [at least attempt to solve the problem yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) before posting on Stack Overflow. It helps us to know how much explanation you need and what problems you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this...

```js
var arr = [{ id: "a5", parent: "a3", value: "great grand child conmpnent" },
{ id: "a1", parent: null, value: "parent conmpnent" },
{ id: "a2", parent: "a1", value: "child conmpnent" },
{ id: "a3", parent: "a2", value: "grand child conmpnent" },
{ id: "a4", parent: "a2", value: "grand child conmpnent" }];

const transform = (arr, parent) => {
    var str = '';    
    for (let key in arr) {
        if (arr[key].parent == parent) {
            str+= '<ul><li id="'+arr[key].id+'"><a>'+arr[key].value+'</a>'+ transform(arr, arr[key].id)+'</li></ul>';
        }
    }

    return str;
}

var generate = (arr) => {
    let parent = '';
    let str = '';
    for(let key in arr){
        if(arr[key].parent == null){
            parent = arr[key];
        }
    }
    str = transform(arr, parent.id);

    return '<ul><li id="'+parent.id+'"><a>'+parent.value +'</a>'+ str +'</li></ul>';    
}

console.log(generate(arr));
```